# What does "giving out with" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Sweet Smell of Success* (1957), press agent Sidney is being confident about the threat he and his newspaper columnist J.J. pose on J.J.’s younger sister’s lover, Dallas:

> Sidney: In brief, J.J., it's all over, because any hour now, that boy
> will give her up. Now, is it a farce, or is it?
>
> J.J: Sidney, this syrup you're **giving out with**...you pour over
> waffles, not J.J. Hunsecker.

What does "giving out with" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means 'saying'.

It's a very stylised, ungrammatical, piece of dialect.

Comment: There is maybe an implication of an excessive, or at least plentiful, amount of 'saying'.

Comment: I have heard Cockneys say things like 'There he was, giving it out with all that', meaning 'There he was, being boastful'.